# MaterialUI Autocomplete - Avoid clearing input text filter when option is selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've imported the Autocomplete component from MaterialUI in my React project and using it as a multiple select with checkboxes: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#checkboxes

I noticed that when I type into the input to filter the list and then select a value, the filter inserted by the user resets. I want to avoid this and continue to multi-select with the filter instead of reinsert it every time. I didn't find any props in the component API to solve this.

Any suggestion?

That's my component code:

```
const VirtualAutocomplete = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const textClasses = textStyles();

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            id={props.id}
            style={{ width: 'auto' }}
            value={props.value}
            limitTags={4}
            noOptionsText="No records found."
            classes={classes}
            disableCloseOnSelect
            ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
            renderGroup={renderGroup}
            onChange={props.onChange}
            options={props.options}
            filterOptions={startsWith}
            multiple={props.multiple}
            renderInput={(params) =>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <TextField {...params}
                        variant='outlined'
                        classes={{ root: textClasses.formControlRoot }}
                        InputLabelProps={{ classes: { root: textClasses.labelRoot } }}
                        label={props.label}
                    />
                </ThemeProvider>
            }
            renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
                <Fragment>
                    <Checkbox
                        icon={icon}
                        checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                        style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                        checked={selected}
                    />
                    {option}
                </Fragment>
            )}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce a working example of the issue in https://codesandbox.io?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a state that holds input value. Then on `TextField onChange` pass the function to change this state. Then on `Autocomplete` pass the props `inputValue` with that state content. You can also use `disableCloseOnSelect` props to `Autocomplete` so options box doesnt close on option selected.

Take a look at their docs about those props https://material-ui.com/pt/api/autocomplete/

Here is a example using their demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-pdh81?file=/demo.js:746-766

Comment: A possible improvement when you want to use it as a searchable select is to clear the input value onBlur. Then the search string ist not left next to your selections.

Comment: Just want to express my thanks for your solution - I was surprised to see that several  early specs and mockups of multi-select autocomplete show the same built-in behavior that MUI provides - that after typing your filter and choosing an option, the filter clears.  This is confusing UX, it stands to reason that you might want to select several related items based on that initial filter.  Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
export const AutocompleteNonClearnableOnSelect = observer((props: AutocompleteProps<any, any, any, any>) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    return <Autocomplete {...props}
                         onInputChange={(_, value, reason) => reason !== 'reset' && setValue(value)}
                         inputValue={value}/>;
})
```